# ReactJS, Calling setState with same parameter

Tags: reactjs

I have been reading the React docs and came across `shouldComponentUpdate()`. My understanding is that everytime `setState()` is called, a re-render of that component will be updated.

My question is that If the value to be updated is the **SAME** as the current state value, would this trigger a re-render event? or I would have to manually checks for the current value and value to be updated in `shouldComponentUpdate()`

Comment: On a side note. While render() might be called, the native DOM is NOT updated when calling setState() with the same parameters as the current state. Thus there is very little performance enhancement by using shouldComponentUpdate() in this case.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The official React documentation states:

> The default behavior is to re-render on every state change...

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

This means that by default, `render()` will be executed if any of a component's `state` or `props` values changes.

You can override this default behavior using [shouldComponentUpdate()](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate). Here's an example that only updates if a state value changes.

```js
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return this.state.someValue !== nextState.someValue;
}
```

Note: this example completely ignores `props`. So, any changes to `props` will not trigger `render()`.

Comment: Very confusing answer. You say "By default ... only if state or props value changes" But then you *override* this behaviour to "Only updates when state value changes". In both you say "State value changes", so what is the difference?

Comment: @kajacx There is nothing to confuse, if you read the last NOTE. As long as you overridden the shouldComponentUpdate, you have the control to re-render the component no matter what changes either it be state or props.

Answer (score 6):

Adding more to @Jyothi's answer regarding implementing `shouldComponentUpdate()` to skip unnecessary re-renders, in `React 15.3` they introduced a new concept `PureComponent`. From [reactjs docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent)

> The difference between them is that React.Component doesn’t implement
>   shouldComponentUpdate(), but React.PureComponent implements it with a
>   shallow prop and state comparison.

This allows to skip unnecessary calls of `render` in class components by just implementing `PureComponent` instead of the usual `Component`. There are a few caveats with `PureComponent` though, from the docs about `React.PureComponent`’s `shouldComponentUpdate()`:

> ... only shallowly compares
>   the objects. If these contain complex data structures, it may produce
>   false-negatives for deeper differences.
>
> ... skips prop updates for the whole component subtree. Make sure all the
>   children components are also “pure”.

Usage of `PureComponent` can in some cases improve performance of your app. Moreover, it enforces you to keep `state` and `props` objects as simple as possible or even better, immutable, which might help simplify the app structure and make it cleaner.

Answer (score 5):

I dont know if I understood your question correctly but react only re renders when there is difference between virtual dom and real dom.

And as Jyothi mentioned in his answer that render method will be called irrespective of the value passed in the set state function but rerendering will depend on what this render method returns.

Comment: This answer covers the react-dom components which were written by the react-dom authors and might have performance optimizations like `shouldComponentUpdate`, but what about the components you write?

Comment: when we talk about "rendering" in react land we don't mean modifying the dom we me calculating what the dom should look like. It's possible for the dom tree to be "rendered" by react and it to result in no change to the actual dom.

Answer (score 0):

In *functional* components, calling `setState()` with the equal value won't cause a rendering, while in a *class* component it does: https://dev.to/sunflower/reactjs-if-it-is-setting-a-state-with-the-same-value-will-the-component-be-re-rendered-5g24

Note that we're just talking about virtual (React) renderings here. Brower-rendering won't happen in any case - i.e. neither in the functional component nor in the class component - as long as the state (or to be more precise: the effective DOM) doesn't change.